# How to extract the URL of a particular page using selenium/python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation

I'm building an instagram Bot using selenium.
How do I extract the URL of a page using python?

For example Selenium is loading a webpage. I want to extract the url of that particular page .(Suppose : https://instagram.com/as80df67s4)

If you still don't understand what I'm talking about, please check the image below. There, I have highlighted the page link. How do I extract that link?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the url in browser input field?

Comment: yes. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From webdriver.py:

```
def current_url(self):
    """
    Gets the URL of the current page.

    :Usage:
        driver.current_url
    """
    return self.execute(Command.GET_CURRENT_URL)['value']
```

This means that in order to get a current url you can use:

```
your_url = driver.current_url
```

But first you need for this page to open.