# How to request data on already open chromedriver tab?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

At this point i auto-logint to a website

```
driver.get("[example link] example.com/124f32fqw")
r = request.get(driver_current_url)
test = r.text
print(test)
```

but it only print the the example link without logint
[Q]
How can i request something from a (selenium) Chromedriver that already open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your_url = driver.current_url
```

I answered similar question recently here [How to extract the URL of a particular page using selenium/python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66959160/how-to-extract-the-url-of-a-particular-page-using-selenium-python/66959337#66959337)

For requests:

```
response = requests.get(url)
response.url
```